# asp.net query with insertion of values in a table

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, vb.net

suppose we have three tables in the Database:

1. tbl_companymaster(company_id(PK),company_name)
2. tbl_papermaster(paper_id(PK),paper_name,rate)
3. tbl_rate(rate_id(PK),company_id(FK ),paper_id(FK),rate)

we have to fire a query of insert on the clicking of a button in asp.net with c# language.

we have to insert the company_id (from tbl_companymaster),paper_id(from tbl_papermaster),rate(sfrom tbl_papermaster) into tbl_rate Example:

tbl_companymaster:

```
company_id     company_name
-----------------------------------
 1            lalit and company
-------------------------------------
 2            deepesah and co.
-----------------------------------
 3                 RP & Co.
-------------------------------------
```

tbl_papermaster:

```
paper_id          paper_name          rate
-------------------------------------------------
  1                 plain             400
------------------------------------------------
  2                 carbon            300
-------------------------------------------------
  3                 butter            500
```

tbl_rate:

```
rate-id        company_id          paper_id               rate
---------------------------------------------------------------

1                 1                   1                 400
--------------------------------------------------------------------

2                 1                   2                 300
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
3                 1                   3                 500
------------------------------------------------------------------------
4                 2                   1                 400
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
5                 2                   2                 300
---------------------------------------------------------------------
6                 2                   3                 500
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please help me with the suitable code.I m in a great trouble with this code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should get a good book on databases. Or hire someone to do this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is a help/Q&A site, not "write this for me".

Comment: Use cross join companymaster and papermaster

Comment: Is this school homework?

Comment: you haven't provided much info. Do you have stored procedures or you want to use Linq to SQL or Linq to Entity

Comment: what you have tried so far  ??  i can give you hint : Use sqlCommand Class with your Insert Into statements.

Comment: **Stop** asking the *same* question repeatedly.  Doing so will possibly lead to moderator action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should aware of Forign key and primary key relationships between the table.As well as the SQL Join. Then only u can perform this much of Insertions and DataBindings to view.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/TableReader.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213227(v=sql.80).aspx

For yours Each company must have uniquidentifier.Based on the company_id (from tbl_companymaster),set Forign Key for paper_id(from tbl_papermaster),set Forign key for rate(from tbl_papermaster) into tbl_rate.Perform the coding operation based on the Key Relationships.

First clear with Relationship then do it. It will be Better.

Hope this may helpful...

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.        Since it seems you have not yet discovered how to accept answers.

Comment: thanks for ur answer.i m writing the exact query in sql but i have to implement it with c# in asp.net